In-place array compaction with least amount of shifting
I've been searching for an algorithm that can do array compaction with the least amount of movement of items. I know I can't go below O(N) and that's fine, but I'm not sure if even that's doable.
I'll use Lua for my examples. I assume -1 as my empty value as using nil will break the array part of the table in Lua (the array iteration only goes until it's first nil).
This is the desired outcome:
local arr = {1,3,4,-1,6,-1,8,-1,-1}
compact(arr)
-- arr: {1,3,4,8,6}

As you can see we only moved one item, 8 from it's old index 7 (lua uses 1-based indices) to it's new index 4.
I tried a few stuff, like iterating the array backwards, setting every -1 to nil (which is deleting that element) and keeping a hash map of free spots in the array that I can fetch so I can still do O(N). Unfortunately that didn't quite work.

You can do this in O(n) by using two indexes: one that moves from the beginning of the list, forward, and the other moving from the end of the list backward. Then, move forward in the list looking for the first empty spot. When you find one, move the index at the end of the list backwards to the first non-empty spot. Swap the two values. Repeat until the two indexes meet.
I should note that this does not maintain the relative order of items in the array. The OP's example suggests that maintaining order is not important.
Here's some pseudocode:
x = 0 // beginning of list
y = n-1 // last item in list
while (x < y)
{
    if (a[x] == -1)
    {
        // move y backwards, looking for the first non-empty element.
        while (y > x && a[y] == -1)
        {
            y = y - 1;
        }
        swap(a[x],a[y])
    }
    x = x + 1;
}


This can be done much more simply while maintaining relative order of elements by just keeping track of the next index to assign elements to.
function compact(arr)
    local sz = 0
    for i, v in ipairs(arr) do
        if v ~= -1 then
            sz = sz + 1
            arr[i] = -1 -- not needed if you ignore the part of the array after the compacted portion
            arr[sz] = v
        end
    end
    return sz -- size of compacted array
end

Usage example:
arr = {1, 3, 4, -1, 6, -1, 8, -1, -1}
newSize = compact(arr)
print(newSize)
-- 5
print(table.concat(arr, ", "))
-- 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1
print(table.concat({table.unpack(arr, 1, newSize)}, ", ")) -- get only compacted portion
-- 1, 3, 4, 6, 8


I'm not sure OP is looking to maintain relative order either since the question states "least amount of movement of items".

The other answer is fine but it's also possible to compress the array in linear time and in-place while maintaining relative order of the non-empty values.
Implementation in Python below.
def make_compressed(A):
    """
    Compress but keep the relative order of non-free elements
    Returns the size of the compressed array though modifications are in-place
    """
    free_idx = 0
    new_size = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(A):
        if x == -1:
            continue
        
        # locate next free index
        while free_idx < len(A) and A[free_idx] != -1:
            free_idx += 1
            
        if free_idx > i: # don't actually swap bc the free index is on the right
            new_size = i + 1
            continue
        
        # do swap; observe that i will later become a free index
        A[free_idx], A[i] = A[i], -1
        # use up this index
        free_idx += 1
        new_size = free_idx
    
    return new_size
    
def main():
    for A in [
        [1, 3, 6, -1, 8, -1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1, 1, 2, 3, -1, 4],
        [-1, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    ]:
        # making copies only for debugging purposes
        B = A.copy()
        new_size = make_compressed(B)
        print(f"{A} -> {B[:new_size]}")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()        


This seems unnecessarily complicated.
